# You Talkin' To Me?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

[image: Title]

Five long time friends whose given names were **Johnny**, **Vinny**, **Frankie**, **Mickey**, and **Bobby**, and whose last names in one order or another were **Morino**, **Bucci**, **Orsini**, **Palmacci**, and **Galino**, although living in the same small town had through the years become more or less estranged until finally the following conditions existed:

#### The Drama

Bucci would only speak to two of the others. Although Bobby would speak to all but one, Johnny would only speak to one of the others. Palmacci and Vinny wouldn't speak, although Frankie and Galino would. Vinny, Frankie, and Mickey were all on speaking terms. There was only one of the five that Morino wouldn't speak to, and only one of the five to whom Orsini would speak.

### Who's Who?

What was each man's full name, and to whom would each man speak?

**EDIT: If A doesn't speak to B, then B also doesn't speak to A.**

[image: chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- > Orsini will only speak to one of the others, so he can't be Vinny, Frankie, or Mickey who are all on speaking terms, and he can't be Bobby who speaks to all but one. So it's **Johnny Orsini**.
- > Palmacci won't speak to Vinny, so he can't be Vinny, Frankie, or Mickey who are all on speaking terms, and we know it's not Johnny. So it's **Bobby Palmacci**, who speaks to everyone except Vinny.
- > Bucci must be one of Vinny, Frankie, or Mickey, so the two he speaks to must be the other two of those. Therefore this is the one who doesn't speak to Bobby Palmacci, so it's **Vinny Bucci**.
- > Morino must be one of Frankie and Mickey, so the one he doesn't speak to must be Johnny Orsini. We also know Frankie isn't Galino, so it's **Mickey Galino** and **Frankie Morino**.

So the five men are

> Johnny Orsini (speaks to Bobby Palmacci)
>  Bobby Palmacci (speaks to Johnny Orsini, Mickey Galino, Frankie Morino)
>  Vinny Bucci (speaks to Mickey Galino and Frankie Morino)
>  Mickey Galino (speaks to Bobby Palmacci, Vinny Bucci, Frankie Morino)
>  Frankie Morino (speaks to Bobby Palmacci, Vinny Bucci, Mickey Galino)

This is assuming that "not speaking to someone" is a symmetric thing: if A doesn't speak to B, then B also doesn't speak to A. I think that's a required assumption in order to solve this puzzle.